# following one directory changes

Tags: linux, bash

My mission is to check if someone changed my directory.
I have path to the directory. In the first time I need to print "*hello*", and on the following times I need to check if there are files that deleted or created between this call to the path and the last time. If files are changed I need to print message: "*file ____ created" or "file _____ deleted*" (change name is equal to delete and create other file).

Comment: And... what is your question, then? Please bear in mind that U&L is not a script writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following command for inspecting files creation and deletion:

```
~/bin/notify.sh echo "hello"
```

from the following script based on `inotify-tools` package.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# file: bin/notify.sh <cmd>

DIR=.
ACTION=$(echo "%f_____ %e")
"$@"
while inotifywait -qre create -qre delete --format "$ACTION" $DIR
do
   "$@"
done
```